# Issues loading text file

Tags: python, text, load

This code has an error on the load function but I don't understand what is causing it.  I'm importing the class definition from another file, the program does save the file as a text in my computer and the program tells me that it loads the data but when I try to call for a display of the data that's when I'm getting the error.

```
from roster2 import rosterClass

outFile = open("c:\roster.txt", "wt")
outFile.write("The text and data will be save as a file on c:\roster.txt")
outFile.close()
inFile = open("c:\roster.txt", "rt")
contents = inFile.read()
print (contents)
def saveData(roster):
    filename = input("Enter file name:")
    print("Saving file.....")
    outFile = open(filename, "wt")
    for x in roster.keys():
        name = roster[x].getname()
        phone = roster[x].getphone()
        jersey = str(roster[x].getjersey())
        outFile.write(name+","+phone+","+jersey+"\n")
    print("File saved.")
    outFile.close()
def loadData():
    roster = {}
    filename = input("Enter file to load: ")
    inFile = open(filename, "rt")
    print("Loading data......")    
    while True:
        inLine = inFile.readline()
        if not inLine:
            break
        inLine = inLine[:-1]
        name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")
        roster[name] = name, phone, jersey        
    print("Roster data loaded succesfully")
    inFile.close()
    return roster

def displayMenu():
    print ("======Main Menu======")
    print ("1.  Display roster ")
    print ("2.  Add player:")
    print ("3.  Remove player: ")
    print ("4.  Edit player information.")
    print ("5.  Save data.")
    print ("6.  Load data.")
    print ("9.  Exit Program")
    print ("")
    return int(input("Select a number to continue: "))

def printRoster(roster):
    if len(roster) == 0:
        print ("no current players in roster")        
    else:
        for x in roster.keys():
            roster [x].displayData()

def addRoster (roster):
    newName = input("Enter new player's name:")
    newPhone = input("Player's phone number: ")
    newJersey = int(input("Player's jersey number:"))
    roster[newName] = rosterClass (newName, newPhone, newJersey )
    return roster

def removeRoster(roster):
    removeName = input("enter player's name to be removed:")
    if removeName in roster:
        del roster[removeName]
    else:
        print("player not found in list.")
    return roster

def editroster(roster):
    oldName = input("Enter the name of the player you want to edit:")

    if oldName in roster:
        newName = input ("Enter the new player's name:")
        newPhone = input("Player's new phone number:")
        newJersey = int(input("Player's new jersey number:"))
        roster[oldName] = rosterClass (newName, newPhone, newJersey)                       
    else:
        print ("no player exist in roster")
    return roster        

print ("Welcome to the Roster Manager")

roster = {}
menuSelection = displayMenu()
while menuSelection !=9:
    if menuSelection == 1:
        printRoster(roster)
    elif menuSelection == 2:
        roster = addRoster(roster)
    elif menuSelection == 3:
        roster = removeRoster(roster)
    elif menuSelection == 4:
        roster = editRoster(roster)
    elif menuSelection == 5:
        roster = saveData(roster)
    elif menuSelection == 6:
        roster = loadData()
    menuSelection = displayMenu()
print ("Goodbye......")
```

Comment: You are missing a quote on the second line of your code. I assume this was just a transcription error when copying to Stack Overflow, but in the future make sure all simple errors like this are fixed.

Comment: Also note that you need to indent code-blocks in function declarations.

Comment: Which error are you receiving?

Comment: Also, you didn't close `inFile` from the beginning of the code

Comment: most of the errors were during transcription, the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ruthlopez/Documents/week6.py", line 108, in <module>
    printRoster(roster)
  File "/Users/ruthlopez/Documents/week6.py", line 62, in printRoster
    roster [x].displayData()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'displayData'

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty of attempting to correct the indentation of your code so that it compiles. Of course it won't run on my computer because I don't have the code that your code imports. However, the diagnostic message you supplied complains that, in ' line 62, in printRoster roster [x].displayData() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'displayData''.

The only place in your code that `displayData` appears is in this line of code:

```
roster [x].displayData()
```

It matches the error message! The message says that `roster[x]` is a tuple which raises my curiosity. How is `roster[x]` defined?

Two **different** ways:

```
roster[name] = name, phone, jersey  
roster[newName] = rosterClass (newName, newPhone, newJersey )
```

I've been programming for nearly fifty years, I can guess which way is correct. What do you think?